# Replace a pattern with a value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm working on an application that have something like that in a string format

```
"lorem ipsum dolor {#variable#} sit amet {#variable2#}"
```

How to remove `{#` and `#}` and replace the word `variable` with `value` and for the second replaces the word `variable2` and replaces it with `value2`

I really appreciate the help.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex `{#(.*?)#}` to find the substrings you want to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Then, use a `map` object to get the corresponding `value` for the captured `variable`:

```js
let str = `lorem ipsum dolor {#variable#} sit amet {#variable2#}`

let map = {
  variable: "value1",
  variable2: "value2",
}

let replaced = str.replace(/{#(.*?)#}/g, (m, p1) => map[p1])

console.log(replaced)
```

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/EVwhA8/1/)